# Jenkins - Start Windows Form

Tags: .net, windows, unit-testing, jenkins

I can't find on the internet a great solution to start a Windows (.net) form via Jenkins. Does anybody know if there is a solution to start a Windows (.net) form unit test via Jenkins?

Thank you in advance!

Jelle

Comment: You can run a shell command in Jenkins -- are you trying to do UI testing?  Aside from turn key desktop tools, there is the MS UI Automation framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are there more options? This framework should implement within the code right?